# Maven Logging for Unit Test Dependencies

Tags: java, scala, maven, log4j, scalatest

I don't know what changed, but starting today when I run unit tests, `mvn test`, the output is terribly cluttered with INFO and DEBUG log4j logging from a certain dependency. How can I configure Maven to silence logging from dependencies for unit tests?

I am using Vs Code with the Metals extension for Scala. I'm not sure what caused it to start today.

Comment: Are the Maven logs or do they come from the application?

Comment: They come from the Apache Flink framework which is used as a dependency

Comment: Do you have any logging configuration?

Comment: No. I tried adding a basic `log4j.properties` file as an argument to the scala-test-maven plugin and under `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` to no effect. I also tried using `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn` which I saw in another StackOverflow post; also to no effect.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?